# What causes the clock to jump back?

Tags: marklogic

A long-running scheduled task failed to complete recently, and on investigation I discovered that MarkLogic has re-started, or at least temporarily shutdown all the databases, due to this problem...

**Critical: Clock jumped backwards 14 seconds**

Does anybody know why that might have happened? And why it causes MarkLogic to react by shutting down?

Neil.

Comment: Probably [this](https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/system-clock-synchronization-and-xdmp-clockskew)

Comment: I had seen that, but in this case there is no cluster - just a standalone single ML server.

Comment: How is time being managed? Is it a VM?  If you are entitled to support, I would open a ticket with MarkLogic Support.  Otherwise, we'll need to see the ErrorLog (and possibly /var/log/messages) to get a better idea of what is going on.  Also, I would change the MarkLogic file log level (group configuration setting) to Debug, as that can provide more information when issues like this occur.

Answer (score 3):

MarkLogic uses the current time in its management of transactions and replication, among other things. Time shouldn't jump backward. When it does, that can cause problems, which is why you got a Critical log message and MarkLogic took steps to avoid data corruption.

As per the link Jeff gave, a MarkLogic cluster should have NTP installed on all the hosts to keep their clocks accurate and in sync. NTP won't let time jump backward (lots of software doesn't like time reversing). NTP will just skew the clock slow for a while until things caught up. Looks like this cluster hasn't been properly configured with NTP.

Comment: Except, as I mentioned above, this is NOT currently a cluster at all. It is a standalone server. However, it will soon be built-out to be part of a cluster, and I am very keen to understand why it happened and to stop it happening again, before we do so.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you have one server or many. If the MarkLogic process detects that you went back in time, it will restart. The system dateTime is critical to how things work, and everyone participating (one server or a multi-node cluster) has to agree on what time it is. If you go back in time, you are at risk for bad and unexpected things happening, so it restarts the process to start with the new time.

Answer (score 0):

@hunterhacker  I agree, for the most part--NTP config issue is likely, but it could be HW or the network (see next paragraph).  Also, BTW, many, if not most, NTP implementations jump (aka "step") the clock, forwards or backwards, including Cisco and Juniper routers, as well as linux/unix depending on the config. I explained this theory in my comment today in Q&A 49624148.  Of course under normal conditions, this should not happen.

"The acceptable level of clock skew (or drift) between hosts is less than 0.5 seconds, and values greater than 30 seconds will trigger XDMP-CLOCKSKEW errors, and could impact cluster availability." (from https://help.marklogic.com/Knowledgebase/Article/View/system-clock-synchronization-and-xdmp-clockskew , referenced by Jeff Holt above) indicates that the NTP "step threshold" is 0.5 secs which is larger than usual, but the "panic threshold" is ONLY 30 seconds which smaller than usual (I wonder what the "stepout threshold" is).  I explained this theory in my comment today in Q&A 49624148.  What I did not mention there is that NTP has upper bounds on link (to the server) delay (asynchronous delay is also an issue) and clock drift (about 500ppm ~= 0.5 msecs ~= 5minutes per week, a typical cheap oscilator).  With the atypical timers (0.5 and 30) here, maybe those rules of thumb do not apply exactly here.  But there certainly are still limits due to "correctness principals".  AFAIK, it is well known that NTP cannot run well on VMs due to the OS delays.  It could be a bad/cheap RTC chip.  The crystals in these can be sensitive to heat.